# I want to be notified when data is added in Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an application with two different package names. There are separate databases for these two applications. If a user adds new data, I want to receive a message. (For example: Added new data to app A or new data added to app B) I don't want to constantly check. How can I do that?

I can receive notifications as Mail, or I can make a different application and an application that controls the content of these two applications. But I don't know how to make notifications.

Comment: *I want to receive a message* How do you want that?

Comment: It could be mail. I can make a different application and check the content of these two applications and receive notifications for that application (which I did to receive notifications). I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

To display notification to a user about a change in the data while they are not actively using the app, you'll typically use Firebase Cloud Message or some other out-of-band mechanism to deliver the message.

To detect the relevant data change and send that message, you'll want to run code in a trusted environment that is guaranteed to continue to run all the time. An example of such an environment is Cloud Functions, which also has an example of [notifying the user when something interesting happens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens).

Comment: I'll have to make a different app to get the cloud functions. but what I don't understand is: How do I get notifications for these two different apps I have? it has different package names after all. do you have an example of that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use cloud functions to trigger events when there are document changes.

Docs are here : https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events.

Then you can tie those triggers with FCM to get notified when doc changes.

Comment: Is there a similar example for java? because I want to receive this notification maybe through another app